# change block size in webhdfs from command line

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I have some files related to a HDFS and I want to browse the image. The block size has been reduced to 64b so that the files are not immediately readable. I followed that tutorial https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html to get the information of all files and directories but when I execute the command **hdfs dfs -ls -R webhdfs://127.0.0.1:5978/** it shows only directories without any files in them.

Is it because the block size it too small, and if so what can I do to increase it?
Please help..

Thanks